# If $A \subset R$ and there is a lower bound for $A$, then there is greatest lower bound for $A$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Hey I need to prove this Statement using definitions.

> If $A \subset R$ and there is a lower bound for $A$, then there is greatest lower bound for $A$

My try:

I drew a number line a take the sets as defined above. And then I mark some lower bounds on the line. And it is clear that there is greatest lower bound for the subset.

How to prove it analytically Or mathematically?

Comment: By $R$, do you mean the real numbers? They are usually denoted by $\Bbb R$ (either `\mathbb R`, or `\Bbb R`) Also, the empty set has a lower bound, but not a greatest lower bound. So you need to specify that $A$ is non-empty.

Comment: I was hoping you would take a hint from the tag changes I've made on your previous question today.

Comment: This really depends on you definition of the real numbers. Axiomatically (with the compleness axiom saying that every non-empty set has a least upper bound, this is pretty easy) or are you maybe proving this for a specific construction of the real numbers?

Comment: $\varnothing$ has a lower bound in $\mathbb R$ but does not have a greatest lower bound in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Consider the set of lower bounds of $A$. It is non-empty and has an upper bound, (why?). Therefore, it has a least upper bound. You should be able to prove that the least upper bound of the lower bounds of $A$ is the greatest lower bound for $A$.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to use the following axiom:

$(AX)$ If $M \subset \mathbb R$ and there is an upper bound for $M$, then there is a smallest upper bound for $M$.

For your proof define $M:= \{-a: a \in A\}$. Then $M$ has the properties in $(AX).$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: It is not mentioned in the question either, but $M$ must be non-empty.

Comment: This is the reverse of the question.

Comment: @learningstudent The answer works for your question. You're allowed to assume that non-empty sets that are bounded above have a least upper bound. You need to prove that non-empty sets that are bounded below have a greatest lower bound. See the third line of the answer for a hint as to how to transform one problem into the other.